# java.lang.ClassCastException error when implementing extent reporting in TestNG XML file

Tags: selenium, testng, extentreports, page-factory

I getting an error telling java.lang.ClassCastException: [My extent report class name] cannot be cast to org.testng.ITestNGListener when running the TestNG XML file as a Test suite.

I have automated a web page using page factory design technique using MAVEN and TestNG which consists of 6 page classes objects initialize in one package. I also written extent report listener class in another package. In addition to this I also has a base class in another package which is the super class of all 6 page object initialize classes. I have written test cases for 3 page classes and base class is the super class of these classes as well.

I have generated TestNG XML file by adding all 3 page test cases and adding extent report class as a listener for this XML file.

I will show the structure of my framework by including one class from each package below.

**Page object initialize package - Login class**

```
package com.crm.qa.pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import com.crm.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.crm.qa.util.TestUtil;

public class LoginPage extends TestBase {

@FindBy(name="username")
WebElement userName;

@FindBy(name="password")
WebElement password;

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='submit']")
WebElement loginBtn;

@FindBy(xpath="//button[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")
WebElement signupBtn;

@FindBy(xpath="//img[@class = 'img-responsive']")
WebElement crmLogo;

//Initializing the page objects
public LoginPage() {

    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

public String validateLoginPageTitle() {

    return driver.getTitle();

}

public boolean validateCRMLogo() {

    return crmLogo.isDisplayed();
}

public HomePage login (String un, String pwd) {

    userName.sendKeys(un);
    password.sendKeys(pwd);

    loginBtn.submit();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


//  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
//  act.moveToElement(loginBtn).click().build().perform();


    return new HomePage();
}

}
```

**Base Package - Test Base class**

```
package com.crm.qa.base;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import com.crm.qa.util.TestUtil;
import com.crm.qa.util.WebEventListener;

public class TestBase {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static Properties prop;
public static EventFiringWebDriver e_driver;
public static WebEventListener eventListener;


public TestBase() {

    try {

        prop = new Properties();

        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\i7\\git\\TestDesignFramework1\\Suresh.com.automationLearning\\src"
                + "\\main\\java\\com\\crm\\qa\\config\\config.properties");

        prop.load(ip);
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public static void initialization () {

    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

    if(browserName.equals("chrome")) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\C\\Selenium\\Chrome Driver\\Extract\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\C\\Selenium\\GeckoDriver\\Extract\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
    eventListener = new WebEventListener();
    e_driver.register(eventListener);
    driver = e_driver;


    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();


    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


}
```

**Test cases package - Login page test class**

```
package com.crm.qa.pages.testcases;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.Assert;
import com.crm.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.crm.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase {

LoginPage loginPage;
HomePage homepage;  

public LoginPageTest() {

    super(); 

}


@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {

    initialization();
    loginPage = new LoginPage(); 

}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void loginPageTitle() {

//  extentTest = extent.createTest("loginPageTitle");

    String title = loginPage.validateLoginPageTitle();

    Assert.assertEquals(title, "#1 Free CRM software in the "
            + "cloud for sales and service");

}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void crmLogoImageTest() {

//  extentTest = extent.createTest("crmLogoImageTest");

    boolean flag = loginPage.validateCRMLogo();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag);
}



@Test(priority = 3)
public void loginTest() {

//  extentTest = extent.createTest("loginTest");

    homepage = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
    System.out.println("Successfully login to the home page of freeCRM");
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {

    driver.quit();

}


}
```

**Test Util package - Extent report listener class**

```
package com.crm.qa.ExtentReport;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;

public class ExtentReportListener {

public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
public static ExtentReports extent;
public static ExtentTest extentTest;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() {

    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:\\Users\\i7\\git\\TestDesignFramework1\\Suresh.com.automationLearning\\Reporting\\ExtentReporting.html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

}

@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result) {

    if (result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) {

        extentTest.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        extentTest.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    else if (result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS) {

        extentTest.pass(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case Passed", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        extentTest.pass(result.getThrowable());

    }

    else {

        extentTest.skip(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case Skipped", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
        extentTest.skip(result.getThrowable());

    }


}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown() {

    extent.flush(); 

}

}
```

**TestNG XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Free CRM Test Application Regression Test Suite">

<listeners>

<listener class-name="com.crm.qa.ExtentReport.ExtentReportListener">
</listener>

</listeners>


<test thread-count="5" name="Free CRM app regression test cases">
<classes>
  <class name="com.crm.qa.pages.testcases.LoginPageTest"/>
  <class name="com.crm.qa.pages.testcases.HomePageTest"/>
  <class name="com.crm.qa.pages.testcases.ContactsPageTest"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 3):

TestNG is working as designed.

Whenever you add an entry such as the one below, into your testng suite xml file

```xml
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.crm.qa.ExtentReport.ExtentReportListener"/>
</listeners>
```

TestNG expects that the class implements one of the sub-interfaces of `org.testng.ITestNGListener`

Your class doesn't do that, which is what is triggering the exception.

Please go through the relevant extent reports [documentation](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#testng-ireporter) to understand how to correctly work with extent reports.

Comment: Krishnan Could you please tell how I can modify the script to generate the extent reports please. If I remove the listener tag from TestNG XML file I will be able to generate TestNG reports. But I want the output in extent report

Comment: @SureshMadhusanka - I would suggest that you please refer to the extent reports documentation for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use "implements IReporter" inside testNG Report class.

In your case the testNG reporting class is "ExtentReportListener" so you have to type:

```
public class FinalReport  implements IReporter 
{}
```